# Does this queue have a variable size?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
  bit    [31:0] queue_1[$];
```

All I understood from the above expression is that the queue instantiated here is of type bit with a size of 32, but I read somewhere that the queue is a variable size parameter.

If a queue is a variable size parameter, then why are we using `[31:0]` in front of it?  Isn't the queue going to be contained in those parameters of `[31:0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SystemVerilog queue is an array whose size is not fixed. It can grow and shrink.

```
bit [31:0] queue_1[$];
```

is a queue of 32-bit, 2-state numbers. The type `bit` is a 2-state type (it can have values `1'b0` or `1'b1`). This would be a queue of 1-bit, 2-state numbers:

```
bit queue_1[$];
```

In SystemVerilog, dimensions to the left of the variable name are called *packed dimensions*. They represent the number of bits in a number. Dimensions to the right of a variable name are called *unpacked dimensions*. They represent the number of elements in an array. So, for example, this is an array of 16 32-bit numbers:

```
bit [31:0] array [0:15];
```